# while() without {}?

Tags: c#

I had  this code in a project in VS2010 - it was a placeholder method I hadn't  fully implemented yet. I started the implementation today.  Notice there are no {} surrounding the if/else for the while statement.  This compiled many times - it has been that way for quite some time.  Is this a bug in VS?  I thought loops all needed {}

```
private void ParsefCIPProfiles(string block)
{
 StringReader reader = new StringReader(block);
 string readline = reader.readline();

 while (readline != null)
  if ()
  {}
  else
  {}
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it isn't a bug.  In fact for single-statement contents, most other scoped statements also don't require the curly braces.  For instance:

```
//This is valid
using (var f = new foo)
    f.Bar();

// So is this
foreach (var i in someInts)
    Console.Out.WriteLine(i);
```

Comment: While this works it's considered bad style. It can lead to bugs, sometimes serious ones (`goto fail` comes to mind) when you (or someone else) add additional line(s) to the body of a conditional expression without also realizing it now needs curly braces added as well.

Comment: The best one is when you are tracing through something, and add a loggin statement betweent he statement and the body, you have totaly changed the code by adding a single print statement which should have done nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Only if there is more than one statement and you want all of those statements to be part of the loop.

Here there is only one if...else statement and that is part of the loop. Anything after that will not be part of the loop and if you want more statements, enclose them in `{..}`

This is the case with `for`, `if`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

See the C# formal grammar: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664812(v=vs.71).aspx

```
while-statement:
    while   (   boolean-expression   )   embedded-statement

embedded-statement:
    block
    empty-statement
    expression-statement
    selection-statement
    iteration-statement
    jump-statement
    try-statement
    checked-statement
    unchecked-statement
    lock-statement
    using-statement

selection-statement:
    if-statement
    switch-statement

if-statement:
    if   (   boolean-expression   )   embedded-statement
    if   (   boolean-expression   )   embedded-statement   else   embedded-statement
```

The important thing to note is that a while-statement requires an embedded-statement, and an if-statement is a selection-statement which is an embedded-statement.

You can derive your sample code with these productions.

Answer (score 2):

You can omit braces when there is just one statement contained in the loop. Or in an `if`/`else` statement.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing, ***syntactically***, wrong with the following statement:

```
while (readline != null)
    if ()
    { }
    else
    { }
```

The `if ... else` is a single statement and will continue until `readline` is null.

Comment: When is `if ... else` not treated as a single statement?

Comment: thanks.  that explains it.  I think I am going to always use the  {} - by now it is habit and it makes the code more readable, at least to me.

Comment: @EJP Oh, I guess it was a 'trick question', although Xander has corrected his post.

Answer (score 2):

Curly braces aren't usually necessary if there is only one statement following, for example:

```
if(readline != 0)
    doSomething();
```

Should work because the function doSomething() is in the if loop's scope. However, what I would expect this code to look like if there WERE curly braces (to identify scope boundaries):

```
while (readline != null) {
     if ()
     { }
}
else
{}
```

NOW the else is not in the scope of the while loop, and I don't see a reason why it wouldn't compile. It just might not behave as you imagine it should.

However, the above code is not quite correct. It does not perfectly mimic your code. If-else statements are considered one statement. Therefore, the scope boundaries are actually looking like:

```
while (readline != null) {
    if ()
    { }
    else
    {}
}
```

Edit: Scope is the context in which an identifier can be used. So, the scope of a variable depends on how it is defined and where. That means the variable can only be used in certain places. The scope of a loop is everything within its curly braces; if it doesn't have curly braces, then only the next statement is within the loop's scope.

This code will work:

```
while(readline != null)
    if(readline == 1)
        doSomething();
```

That code works because doSomething() is in the scope of the if statement which is also in the scope of the while loop.

Comment: I would reword that to "Curly braces aren't necessary in an embedded statement if it is a single statement".

Answer (score 2):

As many of the other posters here have pointed out, the braces are not necessary because the while loop contains only one statement. The `if-else` is considered to be a single statement even though it is split between multiple lines.

However, I always include braces around all nested statements for the following reason. Consider I have the following code:

```
 while (readline != null)
   if (foo = true)
    { DoSomething(); }
   else
    { DoSomethingElse(); }
```

Then later I decide I want to add another statement to my `while` loop:

```
 while (readline != null)
   if (foo = true)
    { DoSomething(); }
   else
    { DoSomethingElse(); }
   DoYetAnotherThing();
```

Oops, see my mistake? The `DoYetAnotherThing()` call will be executed *after* the loop completes, which is not what I want, because I did not include the braces. If I had included them from the beginning, I would not have had this problem. So I think it is generally a good practice to always include them even when there is only a single statement, it helps avoid errors.

There's also confusion that can be caused by the [dangling else problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else) when you don't use braces, but I'll stop rambling and let you do your own research into that.

Comment: +1 for preventing bugs, rather than hunting for them after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

`while()` without `{ }` will execute the next single statement. `if else` constitutes a single statement so it will be executed until `readline` is null.